# What is the difference between KDevelop and KDevelop (Pick Session)?

Tags: kdevelop

I am thinking about trying KDevelop IDE but when I checked Ubuntu Software Center I found two packages: KDevelop and KDevelop (Pick Session). What are the differences between them?

Comment: It's strange! Even Plasma Discover lists them. However, there doesn't seem to be anything related to KDevelop (Pick Session) via the command line; there's just `kdevelop`.

Answer (score 1):

`kdevelop` executable has `--ps` command line option to show a window listing currently created session and allowing you to start the IDE with selected one. It is strange that there two packages for that, though, because the executable being run is same in both cases.